# Is the 2N2222A a suitable transistor choice for a CC LED driver?

Tags: transistors, led, heat

I'm doing an LED project involving high-power LEDs and I'm not sure if I can use the 2N2222A NPN transistor to switch them on and off.

I will be using a constant current LED driver to make the LEDs work properly.

Is the 2N2222A a good choice or there is a better transistor to use for this project?

I'm trying to minimize the heat and the power that's gonna be lost.

LED specifications:

- 3W power
- 3.4V forward voltage
- 600-700mA constant current

Comment: What supply will you be using? What schematic were you considering? 2N2222A is rated 600mA absolute maximum, it will probably not perform very well right at the rating. Typically it wouldn't be used over 100-200mA continuous. There are thousands of transistors to choose from, why ask about this one specifically?

Comment: The supply is a car battery. The plan is to use a microcontroller to trigger the transistor to turn on the LED. I found that 2n2222A is rated for 800mA. I saw that someone was using it in a similar circuit so I figured it may be a good fit for this. Do you have some other recommendations?

Comment: @HalouGen It is impossible to know what transistor works as we have no clue where would you put it and what LED driver you will use and how it works. It is possible that you can't put a transistor before or after the LED driver. It is also possible that you can. But we can't say how it will work with your LED driver.

Comment: Is the transistor to be operated in linear or switching service? In any case, the 2N2222A is inadequate for 600-700mA, for thermal reasons alone. It would also require a lot of base current.

Comment: @HalouGen The 800mA rating is for the metal can variety, which are the ones that *should* be called 2N2222A, the plastic ones are 600mA, and should be called PN2222A or P2N2222A but some manufacturers have taken to calling them 2N2222A. The metal ones cost quite a bit more than the plastic ones.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the specs for the transistor, and determine if it can handle the current and power. The 2N2222A can handle 800 mA continuous, and is rated for 500 mW. If you are using a 5 V supply, the transistor will drop 1.6 volts, and 600 mA, which is 0.96 watts. So it is not suitable for this application. You should look for a transistor in a TO-220 package which may be able to handle this power without a heatsink.

However, if you want to really minimize power, you could use it with PWM and an inductor, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8vc67.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: LED Current]

As you can see, that circuit drives the LED with just 100 mA average current. The 2N2222A will be pushed too close to its maximum current rating if you change the components for your 600-700 mA requirement. The LED in this simulation is not very similar to yours, so you will need to calculate the parameters for your purposes. This simulation just illustrates the principles involved for a low-loss PWM implementation.

Comment: The 1N4148 seems to be pushed to its limits, maybe a sturdier 0.5-1 A Schottky diode would fit better.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the 2N2222A isn't a good choice (given its limits), with that current/power requirement you could be better off with a switching solution.

Unless, of course, your requirement is to **not** have a ripple current - I assume this couldn't be the case, seeing that you're powering from a generic *car battery*, which sounds like a *general lighting* application.

Roman Black expanded his [switching supply solution](https://romanblack.com/smps/a05.htm) with a few targeted examples, even with higher currents (and the 2N2222 in his circuits aren't switching the power lines, of course).

They can be of interest if you would like to dim your light with a lower frequency PWM, over the otherwise regulated higher frequency switching - this is the classical solution for dedicated devices like an [LM3404](https://www.ti.com/product/LM3404)

If you're fine with handling an SMD device, this latest application is very compact and efficient, otherwise, you can consider the non-integrated one.

Another good old solution is with an [MC34063](https://www.onsemi.com/products/power-management/dc-dc-power-conversion/converters/mc34063a) regulator, for which there's still around an original [application note](http://www.madengineer.de/uploads/datasheets/ONS_MC34063A_AN1.pdf).